# OpenAI Embeddings Cosine Similarity Search 'Input vector should be 1-D' error

Tags: python, openai-api, azure-openai, text-embedding-ada-002

**I am getting following error in Jupyter Notebook**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[2], line 39
     37 query = input("Enter your query: ")
     38 print("Recommended contacts:")
---> 39 for contact in search_contacts(query):
     40     print(contact)

Cell In[2], line 33, in search_contacts(query)
     31 scores = {}
     32 for contact, embedding in embeddings.items():
---> 33     scores[contact] = 1 - cosine(query_embedding, embedding)
     34 return sorted(scores, key=scores.get, reverse=True)[:5]

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\scipy\spatial\distance.py:668, in cosine(u, v, w)
    626 """
    627 Compute the Cosine distance between 1-D arrays.
    628 
   (...)
    663 
    664 """
    665 # cosine distance is also referred to as 'uncentered correlation',
    666 #   or 'reflective correlation'
    667 # clamp the result to 0-2
--> 668 return max(0, min(correlation(u, v, w=w, centered=False), 2.0))

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\scipy\spatial\distance.py:608, in correlation(u, v, w, centered)
    575 def correlation(u, v, w=None, centered=True):
    576     """
    577     Compute the correlation distance between two 1-D arrays.
    578 
   (...)
    606 
    607     """
--> 608     u = _validate_vector(u)
    609     v = _validate_vector(v)
    610     if w is not None:

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\scipy\spatial\distance.py:301, in _validate_vector(u, dtype)
    299 if u.ndim == 1:
    300     return u
--> 301 raise ValueError("Input vector should be 1-D.")

ValueError: Input vector should be 1-D.
```

**Here is my Code**

```
import pandas as pd
import openai
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial.distance import cosine

# Authenticate to OpenAI
openai.api_key = "API_KEY"

# Load the CSV file
contacts = pd.read_csv("c:/tmp/connect.csv")

# Generate embeddings for each contact using GPT-3
embeddings = {}
for index, row in contacts.iterrows():
    combined = row["Combined"]
    response = openai.Completion.create(
        model="text-davinci-002",
        prompt=f"generate embeddings for {combined}",
        temperature=0.5,
    )
    embedding = response["choices"][0]["text"]
    embeddings[combined] = embedding

# Search function to return recommended contacts based on a user's query
def search_contacts(query):
    query_embedding = openai.Completion.create(
        model="text-davinci-002",
        prompt=f"generate embeddings for {query}",
        temperature=0.5,
    )["choices"][0]["text"]
    scores = {}
    for contact, embedding in embeddings.items():
        scores[contact] = 1 - cosine(query_embedding, embedding)
    return sorted(scores, key=scores.get, reverse=True)[:5]

# Example usage
query = input("Enter your query: ")
print("Recommended contacts:")
for contact in search_contacts(query):
    print(contact)
```

**My connect.csv file looks like this:**

| Combined |
| --- |
| FullName: Alex Goodwill; Company: HyperCap; Position: Business Consultant |
| FullName: Amy Power; Company: Hollywood; Position: Strategy & Operations - CEO's Office |

Need help with figuring out how to fix this error. I did google search but was not able to find anything which can help me understand how I am passing non-1D array to the Cosine similarity search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to calculate cosine similarity of text instead of vectors. Embedding is a vector representation of text that has a semantic meaning. You do not create embeddings by giving a prompt to completions endpoint. You need to use Embeddings endpoint.

```
response = openai.Embedding.create(
    input=[
        "Sample text goes here",
        "there can be one or several phrases in each batch"
    ], engine="text-embedding-ada-002"
)
```

response will contain embeddings of every phrase. For example:

```
"data": [
    {
      "embedding": [0, 0, 0,....],
      "index": 0,
      "object": "embedding"
    },
    {
      "embedding": [0, 0, 0,....],
      "index": 1,
      "object": "embedding"
    }
  ],
  "model": "text-embedding-ada-002-v2",
  "object": "list",
  "usage": {
    "prompt_tokens": ,
    "total_tokens": 
  }
}
```

So you can take the embeddings from the response and calculate the cosine similarity.

```
response['data'][0]['embedding']
```

Answer (score 1):

Having a look at the openai cookbook I guess the imported embeddings from csv are in string format, you need to convert them back to a list:

```
import ast

contacts['embedding'] = contacts['embedding'].apply(ast.literal_eval)
```